# How can I hide the Fire Fox browser window when using the Ruby Watir gem?

Tags: ruby, watir

I am learning how to use **Watir** on **windows** to automate my browser. I have been searching around and I've found other gems such as headless, which is being deprecated, and Cucumber, but it changes up a lot of the syntax i have already learned.

I'm trying to go for a result along the lines of:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

browser.hidden = true 
#To not show the browser window
#Not correct but if something could do this that would be great
```

Any tips on hiding the browser window?

Comment: I think you are searching for headless browser. Include headless : true like `browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox,headless: true`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly :D !

Comment: Unfortunetly, this question is indeed a duplicate.....